# get data from database using ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I build menu and submenu and from submenu i want to get data from database and insert it into div with content_iv id in index.php page. So, I have get_submenu.php, get_content.php and app.js where I have a ajax code..
here is a get_content.php

```
 <?php
require "inc/config.php";

if(isset($_POST['get_content']))

{  $submenu_id=$_POST['id'];
    $content = $database->select ("vlm",["id", "nazov","kategoria", "opis" ], ['id'=> $submenu_id] );


foreach ($content as $row)
{
    echo"<h3>".$row['nazov']."</h3>";
    echo"<h4>".$row['kategoria']."</h4>";
    echo"<h4>".$row['opis']."</h4>";

    }

    }
    ?>
```

and here is app.js:

```
function get_content(id)
{

$.ajax
({
    type:'post',
    url:'get_content.php',
    data:{
        get_content:"content",
        id:id
    },
    success:function(response) {
        if(response!="")
        {
            $("#link"+id+"#content_div").html(response);
        }
    }
});

}
```

for better understanding here is get_submenu.php..

```
<?php
require "inc/config.php";


if(isset($_POST['get_submenu']))
{
    $menu_id=$_POST['menu_id'];
    $sub_menu = $database->select( 'submenu' ,['menu_id',  'sub_menu'], ['menu_id'=>$menu_id] );


    foreach ($sub_menu as $row )
    {
        echo "<li><a href='' onclick='get_content(this.id);'>".$row['sub_menu']."></a></li>";
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

i thing, that somewhere is missing something, but i don't know where..
thanks for any help

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: $("#content_div").html(response); write this and try again

Comment: still not working :/